# Calling correct virtual methods

Tags: c++, class

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Sport{
protected:
    string name;
    double hours;
    virtual double returnCalories()=0;
public:
    Sport():name("Not defined"),hours(0.0){}
    Sport(string n, double c):name(n),hours(c){}
    virtual ~Sport(){}
    void setName(string x){
        name=x;
    }
    void setTime(double x){
        hours=x;
    }
};

class Running:public Sport{
public:
    static const int CALORIES = 950;
    Running(){}
    ~Running(){}
    double returnCalories(){
        return hours*CALORIES;
    }

};

class Activity{
public:
    Sport* one;
    Activity(){}
    Activity(string n,double time){
        one->setName(n);
        one->setTime(time);
    }
    ~Activity(){}
};

class Diary{
private:
    Activity list_activity[10];
    int counter_activity;
public:
    Diary():counter_activity(0){}
    ~Diary(){}
    void addActivity(Activity x){
    // add activities
    }
    double sumCalories(){
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            if(list_activity[i].one->getName()=="Running"){
                // I want to call  returnCalories() of class Running 
            }   
        }   
    }
};

int main() {

    Activity test("Running",3.2);
    Diary test2;
    test2.addActivity(test);


    return 0;
}
```

Now I have a question:

How is it possible to call returnCalories() of class Running where I want to ? ( it's commented in the code )

Is this even possible, or should I change my logic somehow ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this behavior could be reproduced without all of that irrelevant code you have posted in your question. Don't do that please, provide a [**minimal** reproducible sample](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) [in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31011097/edit) instead.

Comment: The only irrelevant code I can see is maybe addActivity in class Diary and even then someone might say you didn't add anything in your list_activity etc.

Answer (score 2):

It's crashing because you have not initialized Sport *one; and you're attempting to call methods on a null pointer. You need to first create a Running object within the Activity constructor using the "new" operator like so:

```
one = new Running(n, time);
```

Create an overloaded constructor in your "Running" class that takes the appropriate arguments as well, so that you can initialize your variable as shown above.

Comment: Sport is an abstract class and therefore cannot be instantiated.

Comment: I can't create object of class Sport since class Sport is abstract class isn't that right ?

Comment: Well your constructors are not virtual.

Comment: C++ does not allow virtual constructors because you need an object to invoke a virtual method